# Will Elementary OS 32 bits performs better then 64 bits on Intel Atom N455 processor?

Tags: hardware, performance, intel, 64-bit, netboot

I have a Toshiba NB305 PLL3AC-033014 with an Atom N455 (64 bits capable) and 2GB of DDR3 Ram running Elementary OS (Freya 0.3.1) 64 bits installed on a Samsung 120 GB 850 EVO SSD. The performance is OK. The computer is not super slow, but the overall experience is not really fluid. By that I mean I don't really see any transition or animation because they are too choppy, some programs and web pages take forever to open while other take a couple of seconds, Scrolling up and down is almost always laggy, etc.

My question is, will I see a **noticeable** improvement on the overall performance by installing the 32 bits version of Elementary OS, or is the processor on this computer probably just too weak to really provide a fluent experience? Also, if you think the problem can be elsewhere be sure to let me know.

Thanks for your help, Xavier R-T

Comment: 2GB RAM and Intel Pentium T2310 and 64-bit and 400GB HDD = very smooth and usable

Answer (score 2):

While it probably won't result in a noticeable difference, a 32 bit install will use *slightly* less RAM overall as the OS addresses it differently and you don't need to load both 32 and 64 bit libraries into memory if programs require them. Use the `free -m` command to see if you are running out of RAM when these stutters occur.

If you have a little to spare you could look in your BIOS to see if you can allocate more or less RAM to the integrated graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

On [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/products/49491/Intel-Atom-Processor-N455-512K-Cache-1_66-GHz) your processor only capable handle 2GB memory RAM is useless if you use 64bit OS, since pointers can take up twice as much space on a 64-bit operating system. You should go with 32bit version.